# Inferred type 'S' for type parameter 'S' is not within its bound; should extend 'com.data.assignment.domain.Post'

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to do a simple data insert to H2 database, but I end up getting the error

> ```
> Inferred type 'S' for type parameter 'S' is not within its bound; should extend 'com.carepay.assignment.domain.Post'
> ```

My controller

```
  @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    PostDetails createPost(@Valid @RequestBody CreatePostRequest createPostRequest) {
        return postService.createPost(createPostRequest);
    }
```

My service

```
public interface PostService {

    PostDetails createPost(@Valid CreatePostRequest createPostRequest);

    Page<PostInfo>getPosts(final Pageable pageable);

    PostDetails getPostDetails(Long id);

    void deletePost(Long id);
}
```

My Implementation

this is where am getting the error

```
@Service
public class PostServiceImpl implements PostService {
    @Autowired
    private PostRepository postRepository;

    @Override
    public PostDetails createPost(@Valid CreatePostRequest createPostRequest) {

        CreatePostRequest createResponse = postRepository.save(createPostRequest);

        return  createResponse;
    }
```

my repository

```
@Repository
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long> {
}
```

my domain classes

My createPostRequest class

```
public class CreatePostRequest {
    private String title;
    private String content;
}
```

My PostDetails class

```
public class PostDetails extends PostInfo {
    private String content;
}
```

My PostInfo class

```
public class PostInfo {
    private Long id;
    private String title;
}
```

and my Post model

```
@Entity
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String content;
}
```

How can I get the API to post data to the database. I have researched no luck. Thank you in adavance

Comment: Can you also post your `PostRepository` class?

Comment: Hi @pleft i have added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `PostService` you are trying to save a `CreatePostRequest` in

```
CreatePostRequest createResponse = postRepository.save(createPostRequest);
```

However your `PostRepository` knows about `Post` and not `CreatePostRequest`. You have to extract the `Post` object from `CreatePostRequest` and pass it to the save method of your repository.

Moreover your method returns the same type of `CreatePostRequest` => `CreatePostRequest createResponse = ...` instead of `PostDetails`.

Below I changed the `createPost` method you just have to put the missing parts

```
@Override
public PostDetails createPost(@Valid CreatePostRequest createPostRequest) {

    Post post = new Post();
    post.setTitle(createPostRequest.getTitle());
    post.setContent(createPostRequest.getContent());

    Post savedPost = postRepository.save(post);

    PostDetails postDetails = new PostDetails();
    postDetails.setId(savedPost.getId());
    postDetails.setTitle(savedPost.getTitle());
    postDetails.setContent(savedPost.getContent());

    return  postDetails;
}
```

Comment: Hi @pleft.
Kindly expound on the 'extract somehow' comment.

Comment: @Karanja I updated my answer on how to populate `Post` and `PostDetails` assuming your classes have setters/getters